# Calls to system() do not behave the same way as in command prompt (cmd)

Tags: c++, windows, encoding, cmd, system

I need to cut&paste a folder into another folder through code in C++. But some directory names are problematic, such as the ones which have japanese symbols. However, the same commands introduced through `cmd` all work fine.

```
system("move dirName dirName2");      //work
system("move ディレクトリ dirName2");     //does not work (system cannot find the specified file)
system("move ディレクトリ.txt dirName2"); //work
```

Funny enough, if the item which has the japanese symbols is a file and not a folder, the operation works fine even using calls to `system()`.

I have no idea why the second call to `system()` does not work or how to solve it.

PS: I'm working with Windows7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"move dirName dirName2", it is a const char* type, while the Japanese chars are not ASII chars, you should use the unicode API here, try:

```
_wsystem(L"move ディレクトリ dirName2")
```

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that you need to use `_wsystem` instead to accomodate the wide characters.  See [the relevant MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/277bwbdz.aspx)for details, but the syntax of the call is the same.